# Hide Recording Indicator

Tags: swift, avfoundation, ios14

Anyone knows how to hide Recording Indicator in ios14?

I’m writing a camera app, so is very clear that when the app is in use both camera and microphone are in use!

Answer (score 3):

You can't. That's the whole purpose of the indicators: that the developer can't hide that their app is recording audio or video. Even the stock Camera app doesn't do that.